# Regex to extract second float number from a text file

Tags: regex, bash

My text file is having the following values,i want to get only the second float number after the first float number and space so for the first row

```
0,1     0.7302967433402214
```

i want the number 0.7302967433402214 and so in outputted in a text file.

```
0,1       0.7302967433402214
0,2       0.12909944487358055
0,3       0.0
1,2       0.0
1,3       -0.13245323570650439
2,3       -0.936585811581694
```

I want to write a bash script for this

Comment: Just `cut -f2 -d" " input_file > output_file` would work

Comment: Is the second float always in the second column? Ex. `a 1 2`, then you want to get `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the trailing non-blank characters:

Simply:

```
sed 's/.*?(\S+)$/\1/' myfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this, `cut` would do:

```
cut -f2 -d" " < input.txt > output.txt
```

If you have multiple spaces, `awk` would ignore them:

```
awk '{print $2}' < input.txt > output.txt
```